# Upper bound for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k}}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am looking to upper bound the following. One trivial bound is simply $2^n$ which is far too loose. I've tried some other basic things and I get similarly loose bounds. Would anyone know of a way to get a reasonable bound for this?

I plugged it into Wolfram and I get a 3f2 hypergeometric function but this isn't very interpretable.